# Create FB custom audience from user URL

Tags: advertising, facebook, facebook-application, facebook-graph

I have a list of many Facebook users with URLs like:

```
facebook.com/firstname.surname
facebook.com/pseudo
facebook.com/profile.php?id=12345678910xxx1112
```

**How can I create a Custom Audience with these people in http://www.facebook.com/ads/manager/audiences?**

Here I don't see "User URL" field (I tried to upload a CSV with the user URL and it doesn't work):

[image]

If it's definitely not possible, how to get the other fields that are ok from my users URL list, so that I can feed the audience creation tool with these other fields?

Comment: Isn't the Facebook Page User Id part of the URL?   Just take the `facebook.com/` or `facebook.com/profile.php?id=` portion off and use the remaining id.

Comment: It seems that FB doesn't allow to use User ID anymore to feed custom audiences, to avoid FB scraping of users @StephenOstermiller.

Comment: They also got some bad press about the phishing possibilities of targeting an ad at one specific person.